# Align navigation bootstrap center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to center align the navigation links from Bootstrap but since I'm not using the list structure, all solutions don't work.

```
    <section id="menuNavigation">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="´button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHeader">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <a href="index.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Uniongs</a>
                        <a href="sobre.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Sobre</a>
                        <a href="seja-um-doador.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Seja Assinante</a>
                        <a href="blog.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Blog</a>
                        <a href="seja-assinante.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Publicidade</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </nav>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I tried everything: `text-center`, text-align: center, justify-content-center and nothing works.

Comment: Did you try !important? For example, text-align: center !important;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. `ul` can **only** have `li` as children. Try using a `div` instead.

Then use the flexbox helper classes available to you in BS4.

```
<div class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-center">
```

Then we just make the menu full width by adding `flex:1`. The reason the list items wouldn't center is because the menu was not full width and itself, left aligned.

View in Full Page mode.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="menuNavigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="´button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">Toggle</span>
                </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarHeader">
        <div class="navbar-nav d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="index.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Uniongs</a>
          <a href="sobre.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Sobre</a>
          <a href="seja-um-doador.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Seja Assinante</a>
          <a href="blog.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Blog</a>
          <a href="seja-assinante.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Publicidade</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just CSS code added. hope this help you.

```css
.navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-link {
  float: none;
  display: inline-block;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

```html
<section id="menuNavigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="´button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarHeader">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarHeader">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <a href="index.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Uniongs</a>
          <a href="sobre.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Sobre</a>
          <a href="seja-um-doador.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Seja Assinante</a>
          <a href="blog.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Blog</a>
          <a href="seja-assinante.php" class="nav-item nav-link">Publicidade</a>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </nav>
  </div>
</section>
```